# Изменить в owl carousel кнопки prev и next на треугольные стрелки

Tags: html, jquery, css

По умолчанию отображаются надписи кнопок.

По макету нужно вставить стрелки, через css это получается, но вот убрать сами надписи prev и next не удаётся.

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery("#carousel").owlCarousel({
       ...
    navigation : true,
    navigationText : ["",""],
     ....
});
```

указать пустые значения для кнопок. Кстати, если используете иконочные шрифты для стрелок, то можете попробовать там указать коды для них....

Answer (score 1):

Мне нужно было заменить стандартные "prev" и "next" на картинки в OwlCarousel 2-2.2.1 - и вот как я сделал:
1. У меня подключено:

```
owl.carousel.css
owl.theme.default.css
jquery-3.1.1.min.js
owl.carousel.js
```

2. В inedex.html в скрипте который запускает галерейку (не библиотека owl.carousel.js) прописано:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

добавил строчку:

```
navText : ["",""],
```

и получилось:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    navText : ["",""],
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:3
        },
        1000:{
            items:5
        }
    }
})
```

3. Берем 2 класса .owl-prev и .owl-next и (в owl.theme.default.css прописал в конце отдельно) пишем следующие:

```
.owl-prev{
          background-image: url("back.png");
          background-size: cover;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
        }
        .owl-next{
          background-image: url("next.png");
          background-size: cover;
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
        }
```

4. Потом ищем в owl.theme.default.css такую строчку (фон кнопок):

```
background: #D6D6D6;
```

и меняем на:

```
background-color: #D6D6D6;
```

5. Все с этого момента появляются у нас рисунки, те которые мы хотим вставить вместо названий, и тут очень нехорошый момент - при наведении
   рисунки пропадают. Не беда - делаем дальше :)
   ищем (фон кнопок при hover):

```
background: #869791;
```

и меняем все строчки на:

```
background-color: #869791;
```

Вот и все :)

Comment: `Потом ищем в  owl.theme.default.css` - менять код из библиотеки очень не желательно

Comment: особо ничего не изменится

Comment: если обновить ее, то надо правки еще раз вносить

Answer (score 0):

У меня была такая задача: поменять исходные стрелки (содержимое `navText`) на стрелки из макета.

У меня подключено:

- owl.carousel.min.css,
- jquery-3.6.1.js,
- owl.carousel.min.js,
- script.js — это, собственно, нами созданный файл, в котором все и настраиваем.

Не стал подключать никакие шрифты, но уверен что если их скачать и поместить в проект, правильно указать к ним путь, то все точно так же будет работать.

В файле **script.js** у меня:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        dots:false,
        nav:true,
        autoWidth:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            600:{
                items:1
            },
            1000:{
                items:1
            }
        }
    });
  });
```

После `nav` через запятую вставляем `navText` и в нем в квадратных скобках указываем, что `navText` будет у нас `img` и прописываем к ней путь (пусть будет как из нашего файла `index.html`, так как js файл в него загружается и из него все достает). Соответственно, получаем:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        dots:false,
        nav:true,
        navText : ["<img src='ваш путь'>","<img src='ваш путь'>"],
        autoWidth:true,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            600:{
                items:1
            },
            1000:{
                items:1
            }
        }
    });
  });
```

При запуске через локальный сервер картинки у меня отобразились и работают, так же и через index.html файл.